# Getting multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get an three dimensional array.
If I have a hidden field in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="txtHidd[productid][productname][productquantity]" />
```

How can I get it in my form submit page :

I've tried :

```
foreach ($_POST["txtHidd"] as $idProdChc => $prodIdChc) {
  foreach ($_POST["txtHidd"] as $nameProdChc => $nameChc) {
        foreach($nameChc as $quantity){
        }
  }
}
```

But it is not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

```
foreach ($_POST["txtHidd"] as $productid => $product) {
    foreach ($product as $productname => $quantity) {
        echo "$productname with product id $productid and quantity " . $quantity['productquantity'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit.. you don't need the third foreach :)